# Robobrowser BeautifulSoup error

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, robobrowser

I'm making a webscraper to login to a website, when I login I receive a beautifulSoup error which I have no idea how to solve, and an object error which I'm also confused about. I've been looking at web scraping tutorials for a while and really need help

```
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser
browser = RoboBrowser()
login_url = 'http://netacad.com/login'
browser.open(login_url)
form = browser.get_form(id='f')
form['username'].value = "username"
form['password'].value = "password"
browser.submit_form(form)
```

error

```
The code that caused this warning is on line 10 of the file C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 6.0\bin\wingdb.py. To get rid of this warning, change code that looks like this:

 BeautifulSoup(YOUR_MARKUP})

to this:

 BeautifulSoup(YOUR_MARKUP, "html.parser")

  markup_type=markup_type))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Leon/Desktop/retrieve.py", line 6, in <module>
    form['username'].value = "username"
builtins.TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: What error are you getting ? How people going to help you if you don't explain your problem clearly ?

Comment: I'm so stupid haha it was really late at night. I'll put it up when I get home

Answer (score 2):

Try it:

```
browser = RoboBrowser(parser='html.parser')
```